# Getting duplicates from SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this sql query, but I get duplicates. How can I make sure that only one post per inst_id is fetched? I guess it's my group by main_posts.c_p_id that makes it happen, but I get an error if I don't have it since I'm sorting by it. Basically I'm trying to sort and put posts that have a match in main_posts.c_p_id first.

```
SELECT main_posts.c_p_id, insts.inst_id, insts.inst_title
  FROM insts
  LEFT JOIN inst_posts
    ON inst_posts.instp_inst_id = insts.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN main_posts
    ON main_posts.c_id = insts.instp_c_id
  GROUP BY insts.inst_id, main_posts.c_p_id
  ORDER BY main_posts.c_p_id DESC, insts.inst_title ASC
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: I get it but, who said anything about POST or GET?

Comment: Any user data of any form is dangerous. Where does `$p_id` come from? What is `$tagged`? If it's not obvious it's escaped then the only thing we can presume is it's not escaped. Placeholder values make it obvious everything is done correctly, mistakes can't hide.

Comment: @tadman Updated it

Comment: Alright. It's just SQL now, so could even drop the PHP tag.

Comment: Please add schema, sample data, current and desired output.

Comment: You need to atleast show us sample data and expected output

Comment: How are you querying and fetching rows?

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$result = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql)`

Comment: Do you use `mysqli_fetch_array`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes!

Comment: Then use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` with it or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: @AbraCadaver But that only returns one row right? I want all of the rows, but sorted with the ones that has a match from main_posts first.

Comment: In a loop it returns all rows but doesn't return the columns twice.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Switched it out to mysqli_fetch_assoc() but see no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure that only one post per inst_id is fetched?

Since, you haven't provided any sample data, but you mentioned you are getting duplicate rows. Then, you could use `DISTINCT` to show distinct rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT main_posts.c_p_id, insts.inst_id, insts.inst_title
  FROM insts
  LEFT JOIN inst_posts
    ON inst_posts.instp_inst_id = insts.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN main_posts
    ON main_posts.c_id = insts.instp_c_id
  GROUP BY insts.inst_id, main_posts.c_p_id
  ORDER BY main_posts.c_p_id DESC, insts.inst_title ASC
```

> I guess it's my group by main_posts.c_p_id that makes it happen,

Probably.

> but I get an error if I don't have it since I'm sorting by it.

No, you are getting error because, you have mentioned `main_posts.c_p_id` column in `GROUP BY`. The `ORDER BY` will only order the record, it doesn't matter whether you select this column or not.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before, but that filtered out some of the matches from main_posts, which is why I put the  `main_posts.c_p_id DESC`, but that required a group by `main_posts.c_p_id` which again gave me duplicates. Sorry, I'm not very good at this.

Comment: @SeaBass Then, you need to atleast show your data and expected output.

Comment: If I keep the order by main_post but remove it from group by I need to run this to make it work `mysqli_query($db_link, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'")` but it also filters out the matches from main_posts. It's like it found two matches but choose to show the one not from main_posts. I'll see if i can figure out how to give you data. I'm confused about the different tables and how to present it.